# MySQL/PHP: fetchAll() after successful insert return 0 size array

Tags: php, mysql

I insert successfully (I can check with myPhpAdmin that the element has been inserted successfully) an element in the database but then when I fetch the result to get the last inserted entry, I systematically get a 0 size array. This drives me crazy. There is obviously something I don't see, and need help on that one please:

```
public function addSomething($myValue)
{
    // this works fine ...
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`blabla`) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->execute(array($myValue));

    // no luck with that
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    var_dump($result); // always empty

    //return ...;
}
```

I tried `fetchAll` with no more success. When I print the number of row with `rowCount` I got 1??? For example:

```
var_dump(">> " . $result . " " . $stmt->rowCount() . "<<");
```

Gives:

```
string(7) ">> 1<<"
```

Comment: You are not selecting instead `INSERT INTO `

Comment: @Ravi: what do you mean? Isn't it possible to fetch the last inserted entry after an INSERT? Do I need to actually to do a SELECT right after the INSERT?

Comment: what do you mean by last entry ? are you trying to retrieve last row ?

Comment: Yes, I mean to get the row that corresponds to the one I just inserted into the DB using INSERT INTO)

Comment: insert doesn't returns row.

Comment: @Ravi: ok that would be my mistake. I thought it did, and that I had that working in the past (2 years ago when I last programmed in PHP) ... so what would be the solution to this? Follow the INSERT with a SELECT? Thx

Comment: But you can use `$this->pdo->lastInsertId()` to get the generated AUTO_INCREMENT value.

Comment: At those who down-vote. This is well formed and pertinent question. That it looks obvious to a PHP/MySQL expert doesn't mean it is to a newbie. I spent 2H looking for an answer and on the things I read there was no indication that INSERT wouldn't return the last inserted ROW (which to honest would be a useful feature). If you don't like the question, just pass on. When people will stop judging others, maybe we will go somewhere ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ravi and Paul ... Hopefully that will be helpful for someone else.

**insert doesn't returns row**

So to get something working I guess you need to do something like:

```
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE row_id=?");
    $stmt->execute(array($this->pdo->lastInsertId()));

    // return the full new inserted comment
    return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```